# Can I remap a shared POSIX mutex while it is locked?

Tags: pthreads, posix, mutex, mmap, remap

Assume that the shared POSIX mutex has allready been initialized (using PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED).

Then, consider the following procedure:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    // ...
} Shared;

Shared *shared = (Shared *)mmap(...); // MAP

pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->mutex); // LOCK

// REMAP
munmap(shared, ...);
shared = (Shared *)mmap(...);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->mutex); // UNLOCK
```

Does POSIX guarantee that this will work as "naively" intended?

As far as I can see, none of the relevant man pages mention such a scenario.

---

Also, what about the following Linux specific alternative:

```
Shared *shared = (Shared *)mmap(...); // MAP

pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->mutex); // LOCK

shared = (Shared *)mremap(shared, ...); // MREMAP_MAYMOVE

pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->mutex); // UNLOCK
```

---

I can imagine, for example, a PTHREADS implementation that will store a pointer to a locked mutex somewhere inside the process. If the mutex is configured as robust (PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST), it would allow the implementation to mark the mutex as 'abandoned' if the process dies while the mutex is locked.

I have no idea whether such a scheme would actually work, whether it is allowed by POSIX, or how mutex robustness is actually implemented on any platform, but if an implementation along these lines **would** work, and **would** be valid according to POSIX, then the remapping scenario above would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work just fine.

Comment: @Celada: I added a section on how I can see that it might fail, depending, of course, on what constraints POSIX puts on the implementation.

Comment: Very good point about robust mutexes. I think you answered your own question! Because of the way [those are maintained by glibc in a linked list](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/robust-futexes.txt), I guess the assumption is that their memory address won't suddenly change while they're being held.

Comment: @Celada: Thanks for pointing to that piece of documentation. And what a wonderfully well written piece of documentation that is. I completely agree with you that this means a locked mutex must remain at a fixed address.

Answer (score 2):

No!

As pointed out by @Celada, the implementation of robust mutexes in Linux assumes that a locked robust mutex remains at a fixed address:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/robust-futexes.txt

From this we can conclude with some certainty that POSIX allows for implementations that **prohibit remapping** of a locked mutex. Otherwise the Linux implementation would be incorrect.

Ergo, the procedure that I outlined in my question should be regarded as **incorrect**, and leading to undefined behaviour.